# Using Laravel Sail on an existing Laravel application

Tags: laravel, docker, composer-php, laravel-sail

- Sail Version: 1.16.2
- Laravel Version: 9.37
- PHP Version: 8.1
- Host operating system: macOS 12.3

#### Description:

I want to use Sail on my existing Laravel application.
As following to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects), i need to execute this command to install sail & other composer dependencies:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

When i run it, everything is going well until composer install crashes with this error:
`Install of google/apiclient-services failed`
`In Filesystem.php line 314: Could not delete /var/www/html/vendor/composer/cc83f9bf/googleapis-google-api-php-client-services-52b4942/src/OrgPolicyAPI:`

#### Steps To Reproduce:

- Install new laravel application
- Delete vendor folder if you have one
- Add "google/apiclient": "^2.12.6" to your composer.json
- Execute the docker run command above
- Error occurs

Can someone help me solving this?

Comment: Check the file ownership and mode of that directory both in the container file-system and on your local file-system where it is mounted. Compare. Does the user in the container has enough rights to delete that directory? The diagnostic message looks to me that there are insufficient rights for the delete. IIRC `"$(id -u):$(id -g)"` is from a different system on the Mac operating system as the containers are running on a different (virtual) machine there. Leave the user option and argument out, the virtualization should do the mapping for you.